# Hiera hierarchy doesnt respect facter

Tags: automation, puppet, devops, hiera

## Background

My hiera.yaml looks like

```
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: /etc/puppet/hieradata
hierarchy:
  - name: "YAML data: environments, stages, roles, common"
    data_hash: yaml_data
    paths:
      - "roles/%{role}/common.yaml"
      - "roles/common.yaml"
      - "common.yaml"
```

hieradata folder have following files

```
/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/development/common.yaml
/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/common.yaml
/etc/puppet/hieradata/common.yaml
```

all the above files have following content

```
---
foo : "bar"
```

my facter output is given below

```
[root@allinone puppet]# facter role
development
```

## Problem statement

when executed the `puppet lookup foo` command, outputs `bar` as expected.

I deleted the file `/etc/puppet/hieradata/common.yaml` and still outputs `bar`. This is fine.

But when i deleted `/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/common.yaml` also output doesn't show anything. It doesnt respect the file `/etc/puppet/hieradata/roles/development/common.yaml` Any reason?

I can see the fact `role` using the facter command. But my hiere doesnt respect that.

I have also tried the following in hiera.yaml

```
- "roles/%{::role}/common.yaml"
- "roles/%{facts.role}/common.yaml"
```

but nothing helps

Comment: Your `hiera.yaml` is invalid YAML. `data_hash` and `paths` should align with `name` (i.e. two indents less.

Comment: Sorry @Anthon! That is markdown issue. Fixed in the original question. Actually they are aligned. But no luck.

Comment: Definitely keep it at `%{facts.role}` as that is the valid entry of the ones you attempted. Try `puppet lookup --explain` for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tedious debug process, The issue was with the facts file.

Those facts files were having **Windows style line endings**. After changing to linux style, everything worked.

Comment: Thanks to my colleague Marc.